# UIButton frame coordinates aren't updated after View is moved

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a scrollView with a bunch of buttons + textfields, and when data is entered in one element, the scrollview scrolls to the next element. I'm accessing each elements location via the `frame` component

However, the user can upload an image, which intentionally moves *all* those elements down the page. This completely breaks the scrolling to the next element functionality, and it is only scrolling to *where the elements used to be*. Meaning, the `frame` component for each `UIButton`, `UITextField` isn't getting updated.

When I move all those elements down, how do I get their coordinates updated? Should I not be using `frame`?

For more detail, the fields actually sit on a View, which then sits on top of the `UIScrollView`. When I add the image, I move the field View by shifting the frame down the screen. I'm not moving each button/field itself.

```
- (void)scrollViewToNextElement:(CGRect)frame {
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Trigger action:

```
-(void)button1TextEntered{
// Now go to the next button
[self scrollViewToNextElement:button2.frame];
```

}

Comment: you can use the `center` property of the elements as well, it is faster than changing the `frame` property in every time. (because the `center` property won't redefine the size of the elements)

Answer (score 0):

Take the scrollview frame and reduce the frame `origin.y` by some value. When you enter value and press enter scrollview `origin.y` value will move up. This way you can fix it.